AWS Loadbalancer healthcheck issue: bitnami/moodle application deployment
Deploying moodle application by ECS using bitnami/moodle:4.3 image , when I connect my container task ip as a target to application load balancer , I am getting unhealthy target status. I made configuration changes in health check parameters of target group, still no luck. Also, can't make any configuration changes in image as can't install any text editor over there.
port mappings as follows- container port= 8080 (HTTP) and 8443 (HTTPS).
I tried with postgresql database, also checked network configurations (such as ecs and load balancer vpc and subnet compatibilities), security group inbound outbound rules compatibility for load balancer and ecs, database.
